# What does this error mean and how do I correct it: Image Loading: Image failed to load: E_NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I am unable to display images in my Xamarin app. The image is in the root folder. I have tried different images. I have tried changing property to Content. I get this error message when running Debug:  "Image Loading: Image failed to load: E_NETWORK_ERROR" I cannot find any info about it anywhere. The image is on my hard drive. What does it mean? I have google search. I have read the microsoft docs on image control. I have successfully displayed images in the past. Here is the code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Images.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Image  Source="logo2.jpg"/>
       
       
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: where is the code you are using to load images?  Have you read the docs on using images?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos

Comment: You say “the images are in the root folder” which does not sound like you are following the docs

Comment: Here is what the documentation says: Universal Windows Platform (UWP) - By default, images should be placed in the application's root directory with Build Action: Content. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: In the future it helps if you include relevant info like what platform you’re targeting in your original post.  Are they in the root of the UWP project or the shared Forms project?

Comment: Any further insight into this?  I am seeing the same errors in my app (all platforms).  Any insight would be appreciated.